# CSS dropdown menu disappears

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I am very new to CSS coding. I'm having trouble with dropdown menu where the menu li disappears when mouse moves outside ul part where on the li items. I want mouse to hover on li items, but the menu li disappears..
Here is my codes:

HTML code:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbtn" Text="Sort By Date" CssClass="lbtFilter">
    <ul>
        <li>List item 1</li>
        <li>List item 2</li>
    </ul>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

CSS code:

```
.lbtFilter {
    text-decoration:none;
    margin-left:27px;
    position:relative; 
    z-index:9999;

}
.lbtFilter ul {
    display:none;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin-left:20px;
    width:160px;
    height:60px;
}
.lbtFilter:hover > ul {
    display:block;
}
```

I tried adding this line to CSS but did not work:

```
.lbtFilter:hover ul >li{
    display:list-item;
}
```

Can you show me where my mistake is?

Comment: well, you have `  display:none;` why do you need it ?

Comment: can you make a JSfiddle ? so we can play with it !

Comment: of course it will, you're declaring the hover over that`UL`, so once it's not hovered, the `ul` returns to `display:none`. Also, I have no idea why are you including an `ul` element in a button

Comment: @Fabio Because I need to write some code in codebehind in asp.net using linkbutton. I writed display:none in ul, Otherwise it always displays submenu (ul), but i want to display it only when Mouse hovers the linkbutton

Comment: but without display:none , menu items is always being displayed @FranciscoCorralesMorales .  I want to Show them only when Mouse hovers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<a id="lbtn" class="lbtFilter" onmouseover="me()">
List
</a>
<ul id="mylist" class="ulist">
<li>List item 1</li>
<li>List item 2</li>
</ul >
```

**CSS**

```
.lbtFilter {
text-decoration:none;
margin-left:27px;
position:relative; 
z-index:9999;
}
.ulist {
margin-left:20px;
width:160px;
height:60px;
display:none;
}
.ulist li:hover{
color:red;
}
```

A simple **JavaScript** function:

```
<script>
function me() {        
document.getElementById("mylist").style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BADpn)**

Comment: Sorry, i've changed my question a bit to be clearer.

Comment: I don't understand what you really want. can you be a bit more clear please?

Comment: @linda: do you want a hover effect on your `li`? some thing like [THIS](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BADpn)

Comment: I want to be able to walk on the menu items, when it hovers link (as your example it hovers <a>). But, I had to write display:none into .lbtFilter ul, because this menu is not going to be displayed without hovering Mouse on <a> tag. I hope I could explain because English is not my mother language, sorry about that.

Comment: The `UL and li` will only be displayed when you move mouse on the text of `<a>` tag. and after being visible it will also have hover effect as you want.